# swapping bytes in a file in c++

Tags: file, pointers

assume that there is a file named "swaplt.doc" which contains more than 200bytes of data.now write a program that will encrypt the file by swapping its first 100 bytes of data with last 100 bytes.

Comment: Studying for your exam on the 9th again, are you?

Comment: We're here to help, not to do your work for you. Which part of this are you stuck on, what specifically do you want help with?

Comment: ya...couldn't find the code for more than an hour...

Comment: Doesn't sound like very good encryption.

Comment: @Fred:  It's likely for a class, but otherwise it could be called PBP. :)

Comment: @John: True. But this assignment is probably doing the students a disservice by calling it "encryption".

Comment: @nafiz: usually you don't *look* for code, you *write* it.

Comment: ya ...i mean i dont understand how to move the file pointer from 1st to 100th byte...that kept me stuck so long.

Comment: @nafiz: then ask the appropriate question: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/

Comment: @nafiz: Instantiate a byte pointer (something like `unsigned char *myPtr;`) and set it to the address of the first byte of the memory you loaded the file into (`myptr = &myMemory[0];`). (`myMemory` is an array of unsigned chars.) Moving the pointer means setting it to a different part of the myMemory array.  Or, alternatively, you can just pull the stuff you need to switch into memory, and move around within the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create two buffers of length 100 bytes each, say *A* and *B*.
2. Read 100 bytes from file to *A* (assuming that the file cursor points to the beginning of the file).
3. Seek to file length *n*-100.
4. Read 100 bytes from file to *B*.
5. Again, seek to file length *n*-100.
6. Write 100 bytes from *A* to file.
7. Seek to file position 0.
8. Write 100 bytes from *B* to file.

Answer (score 12):

1. Read the file into memory
2. Modify the memory
3. Write the memory back to file

Comment: A question this poor in quality only deserves excellent answers. This is one of those answers.